# Scammed $3,000, bank closed my account due to insufficient funds

Tags: united-states, scams, gift-card

I was scammed thinking I was working for a Company that they lied about.  They said that they were going to send me a $3,000 check to cover Office Supplies so that I could get set up for training the following week.  They also had me buy ebay cards from CVS that totalled $3,000.  I tried to explain what happened at the bank but they said it is out of their hands and I owe the $3,000 back and they closed my account.  What can I do now that I am out $3,000 because I got scammed.  I only had $1,000 in my bank account and I don't have any money left?  Should I try to talk with my bank about payments?  I've reported to the Police online and I don't know what else to do.  I have no money now....is there any advice or legal actions I can do?

Comment: Related: [Amazon gift card scam](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/amazon-gift-card-scam/)

Comment: Did you report the cards stolen to eBay? When you bought the cards, did you indicate or agree that you weren't buying them for anyone else or were you asked about why you were buying them?

Comment: What are ebay cards from CVS?  (CVS the pharmacy???)

Comment: @Michael: CVS is a nationwide chain of retail stores that sell many things, although stressing hygiene, personal care, and beauty (so-called), in addition to (usually) a pharmacy. Among these many things are prepaid-value (aka gift) cards for hundreds of other businesses, including ebay.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to hear this.

Whenever buying gift cards is involved it seems like an immediate scam to me.

Another scam is them sending a check and you get to deposit in your bank account. Later that check bounces.

My guess is local authorities would be unhelpful since probably the scammers are international rather than domestic.

The best bet is to try to talk with your bank that you got scammed and see if they can waive the payments. The extra 2000$ you spend was it on a credit card?

Do you have receipts from CVS? Talk to the eBay fraud department (send them scanned receipts) to see if they can track the gift cards since probably they haven't used it. Remember whenever someone buys a gift card it has to be active at the time of buying.